# Farsi.Library 2.7.0 Fails to install

Tags: c#, nuget, datetimepicker, farsi

I tried to install [Farsi.Library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Farsi.Library/2.7.0) 2.7.0 through the NuGet Package Manager Console.

But following error occurs:

> Install-Package : Could not install package 'Farsi.Library 2.7.0'. You
>   are trying to install this package into a project that targets
>   '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2', but the  package does not contain any
>   assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
>   framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to his [blog entry](http://www.seesharpsoftware.com.au/farsilibrary-v2.6-now-available/) all versions of this library beyond and including version 2.6 are based on .NET Framework 4.6 - somehow this fixes a few bugs with the persian calendar. This is why the installation fails for you.

Install version 2.5.1.5, the latest version of this library which is based on .NET Framework 2.0, to bypass this.
*Or upgrade your project to .NET Framework 4.6 or later.*

> Install-Package Farsi.Library -Version 2.5.1.5

Comment: do you have any experience in Persian DateTime Picker   @jAC

Comment: No, sorry, don't have the slightest clue about Persian DateTimes.

Comment: I was able to download the Farsi.Library 2.7.0 source code and compile it against .Net Framework 4.5.2. I'm not at all leveraging the library in my code so I'm not able to comment on any reintroduced bugs.